# Getting error whenever trying to add a repository

Tags: linux-mint, repository

Whenever I try to add a repository I get a `NoDistroTemplate Exception`. I am using Linux Mint 14 Nadia.

```
tusharmakkar08@tusharmakkar08-Satellite-C660 ~ $  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 

You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK6 / JDK7 / JDK8). 
 There are no actual Java files in this PPA. 
 More info: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 161, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 592, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 87, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException("Error: could not find a "
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template
```

How to remove this exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is pretty self explanatory. The PPA you're attempting to add does not provide packages for your particular version/release of Mint. At least not at the PPA level, even though the packages may be completely compatible.

Take a look at this [Q&A on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126498/12-04-reports-itself-as-quantal-after-installing-the-toolchain-test-ppa/135472#135472), specifically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/135472/17531).

There is a solution that you can try but it isn't really the recommended approach for dealing with this particular issue:

**excerpt from [this forum post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=85692):**

> The error regarding distribution template is refering to the file
>   "/etc/lsb-release" It should read something like...

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

> The ubuntu version depends on the version of mint you are using. You
>   should be able to change the DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION to change the name of
>   the OS during grub boot but you can't change the rest without breaking
>   the source.list distribution template.

Comment: So what do you recommend ? Should I change "/etc/lsb-release" file ?

Comment: You could try that but I'd make a copy of the lsb-release file prior to trying it.